# Address Formula in Google Sheet

Tags: excel, formula

I am new to Excel and need help in resolving below error

=ADDRESS('18/05/2020'!B86&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH("Debtors Total",'18/05/2020'!G:G,0), COLUMN(G2)))

I need to keep my range dynamic. The Range should be from B86 to Column G wherever cell value is Debtors Total.

So Ideally it should return ('18/05/2020'!B86:G98)

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO... If you are looking for address try `="'18052020'!$B$86:"&ADDRESS(MATCH("Debtors Total",'18052020'!G:G,0),7,1)` .. I don't think sheet name can have "/" so i removed it this comment. ... Result is like `'18052020'!$B$86:$G$100` if "Debtors Total" is in G100 on sheet 18052020 .. Note that 7 is columns number for G in match address function.

Comment: Thank you very much.. IT worked. My Sheet has "/" in file name.. I am using Google sheets.